# Change Default JSON Provider on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: json, jaxb, websphere, jax-rs

I need to know how to override the default JSON Provider on a WebSphere Application Server Environment (versions 8.0 and 8.5). I need to do that due a to an issue found on Jackson library version 1.6 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/3).

If anyone could help would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite get whether you want to avoid using Jackson at all or you just want a different version.

In your application you can register the providers you want. For example, to use Jettison you need the following:

```
import org.apache.wink.providers.jettison.JettisonJAXBProvider;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        JettisonJAXBProvider jaxbProvider = new JettisonJAXBProvider();
        singletons.add(jaxbProvider);
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

If you need different Jackson version, why not just put it into WEB-INF/lib and set web module classloading policy to PARENT_LAST?