# Spring boot : org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "XX" in WebSphere

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, websphere-liberty

I have a spring boot application that execute a reverse `Swagger` `Yaml` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-swagger-java</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/cview.yaml</inputSpec>
                <apiPackage>client.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>client.model</modelPackage>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <library>jersey2</library>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running with a main class, it works well

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
 SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
}
```

But when I run it with `SpringBootServletInitializer` on `WebSphere libertyCore` it stucks and gives me those errors when I try to call a web service :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id_entite" (Class client.model.GaEj), not marked as ignorable

Problem with reading the data, class client.model.SearchResultGaEj, ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

the problem is that i dont have any dependency with `org.codehaus.jackson.*`

I only use `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype`

Comment: Make sure that when deploying you are using parent-first/system-last class loading.

Comment: i dont understand !

Answer (score 0):

By default, `WebSphere` uses `Codehaus Jackson` ([reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/opensourcesoftwareapis.html)). `WebSphere` uses two [Class-loader modes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/crun_classload.html): `Parent first` and `Parent last`. You need to be sure that application uses `Jackson` from [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML) not from `Codehause`. `Spring Boot` does not have any own managed libraries but `WebSphere` is an `Application Server` which provides many already attached libraries so you do not need to provide them with your app.

See:

1. [Catch JsonProcessingException from Jackson in Websphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/294672/catch-jsonprocessingexception-from-jackson-in-webs/)
2. [Change Default JSON Provider on WebSphere Application Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074017/change-default-json-provider-on-websphere-application-server)
3. [Override Jackson Object Mapper properties on Websphere 8.5.5 using Apache Wink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468429/override-jackson-object-mapper-properties-on-websphere-8-5-5-using-apache-wink/34362374)
4. [How to change Jackson version in JAX-RS app (WebSphere Liberty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388651/how-to-change-jackson-version-in-jax-rs-app-websphere-liberty/39395944)

Comment: Ziober   the question is : should i add or remove feature from my server.xml ? because on my machine works correctly, so when i deploy on WebSphere here the problem comes !

Comment: On your machine you do not use `WebSphere`, you use `Spring Boot` with embedded web server: `Tomcat` or `Jetty`. On these two servers this problem does not appear. It appears on `WebSphere` because it contains inside much more than simple `HTTP` server. Have you read articles I referenced to? Right now I am not able to point exactly what you have to remove, I hoped you read these articles and dig into documentation and configuration by yourself. More or less this is a general problem with servers like `WebSphere` or `JBoss` for which we need to disable internal libs and change path order.

Comment: Take a look also on this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html), it describes how to configure `ParentLast` `ClassLoader`.